# How to disable Fortran option -DNDEBUG in cmake when i set -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release?

Tags: cmake, intel-fortran

I had subroutine that had NDEBUG in variables using Intel Fortran compiler.
If I use `cmake` for Release `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` automatically gave error
since it var will change value of 1.

```
error #5082: Syntax error, found INTEGER_CONSTANT '1' when expecting one of: %FILL <IDENTIFIER>
      INTEGER(LONG), PARAMETER        :: 1        =  250   ! Size of DEBUG array
-----------------------------------------^
```

it was

```
     INTEGER(LONG), PARAMETER        :: NDEBUG        =  250
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

in Cmakelists.txt, removing /DNDEBUG in CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT any any release. as can be see in the intel.cmake

```
if (${__WINDOWS_INTEL} MATCHES 1)
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "/O1")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL_INIT "/O1")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "/O2")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT "/O2")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "/O2 /debug:full")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO_INIT "/O2 /debug:full")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE= /O3 /Ob2)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT= /O3 /Ob2)
endif()
```